# How long ago was Frank Castle's family killed?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

Prior to the events of season 2 of *Daredevil*, Frank Castle lost his family.

We see

> Karen go to Frank's house and finds it largely untouched. It has not been sold, and Frank says he has not been there since the deaths.

We learn that

> District Attorney Reyes has been covering up the details of the deaths and that ADA Blake Tower got his job some time after the coverup began. He does not, however, seem to be a recent hire during the events of the show.

**How long ago were the Castles killed?**

Comment: I am not sure about it, but the title is a little bit spoilery. Where I am living (France), the Punisher is not a well-known character.

Comment: @Taladris I debated spoilering this, but this is a well-known origin, and it's something that's revealed very early in the show. If anyone feels strongly about it, I'm not adverse to reasonable spoiler edits being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Speculative:

My bet would be about 8 months before the last episode of Daredevil.

When Karen is looking through old papers (s2E5), she mentions the date "April 14th" as approximate time when information about Frank's family should be printed.

> Karen: Well, these are all the papers from the week that Castle was shot. I've been through them three times and there is not a single mention of Castle, his family... not even John Doe that matches. Just nothing 
>  
>  Mitchell : Well you know, people are shot every day. It doesn't always make the paper [...] April 14th... When was the Castle's family murdered? 
>  
>  Karen: Well, I've figured out it must been sometime that week, right? 
>  
>  Mitchell: You know, I cannot remember my kids' birthdays, but violent, soul-sucking events are just seared into my brain.

In last episode Mitchell gives Karen a Christmas gift, so we can guess that the action of the series happen around the end of December

Unfortunately I don't know exactly how much time passes between first and last episode of Daredevil, but as @Kevin Workman pointed it seems that there is quite hot outside, which would put it at summer/early autumn.

Comment: why the hell spoiler markups don't work?

Comment: Apparently, you have to use html to get a spoiler block with breaks:  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/how-to-hide-list-or-multi-line-text-behind-anti-spoiler

Comment: Note that this means the killings took place 8 months before the last episode. In the first episode of the second season, it's over 100 degrees outside, which places the first episode somewhere between June and August. So the killings take place 2-4 months before the first episode.

Comment: Good point, I'll add it to the answer.